# How to manipulate rendered data table that uses a reactive expression?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, reactive-programming

I'm quite new with using Shiny. The code below is actually part of an Rmarkdown file with Shiny coding in it.

I have an issue in handling reactive expressions within Shiny. Basically after calling a reactive expression, I can render or plot the expressions. What I cannot easily do is to manipulate that data after calling it.

I've managed to render and output `load_table()`. This just tells it to load the csv file on a button click. See code below:

````
```{r UI inputs}
wellPanel(
  fileInput("dataset", label = "Select a .csv File to upload",
            accept=c("text/csv",
                     "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                     ".csv")),

actionButton(inputId = "loadbutton", label = "Load Data")
)

dataTableOutput("df")

```

```{r Server Functions}
load_table <- eventReactive(input$loadbutton, {
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$dataset

    if (is.null(inFile)){
      return(NULL)}
    else {
      read.csv(inFile$datapath)}
    })

output$df <- renderDataTable({
  load_table()
})
```
````

My output
[image]

An example of a file I loaded
[image]

However, once the user selects and loads the data - I can't seem to manipulate it because the reactive expression `load_table()` doesn't work like a dataframe I'm used to.

What I want to do next is to manipulate `load_table()` in any way possible. For example, filtering the data by date range or just simply adding additional columns. But I can't seem to manipulate `load_table()`. And I can't get the table without using a reactive function.

I know there are similar questions already being asked on StackExchange, but it never seems to be what I need. What am I missing here?

Regards
Z

Comment: `load_table()` is a reactive data.frame that you can manipulate. e.g. `load_table()$Year` will select the year from the data.frame.

Comment: @troh

I must be doing something wrong because I can't get `load_table()$Year` to display.

I've added:


`output$Year <- renderDataTable(load_table()$Year)`



and then


`dataTableOutput("Year")`



Nothing was displayed

Comment: Try `load_table()[ , "Year"]`. You have to have an expression that returns a dataframe or matrix. https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderDataTable.html

Comment: @troh

Thank you! This worked for me but I have to throw away the comma, which is strange since when I checked its structure, R says it's a dataframe. 

anyway, thanks again. I can work with this at the moment to develop a more complex ShinyApp.

Comment: When you only select one column, base R is simplifying the data structure behind the scenes. If you select more than one column, it will keep the dataframe structure or you can wrap `data.frame` to reconvert it.